# I am trying to use a kms key alias in a bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the following bucket policy:

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1566337631537",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt156",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::jmalacho-test-bucket23/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:123456789012:alias/ExampleAlias"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Then when I try to upload a file using the CLI I get an Access Denied error.

aws s3 cp notes.txt s3://jmalacho-test-bucket23/notes.txt --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id alias/ExampleAlias

If I use the key-id arn, the pollicy works.  Is it not possible to use an key-alias in a bucket policy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The documentation suggests that you cannot.

> Amazon S3 also supports the `s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id` condition key, which you can use to require a specific KMS key for object encryption. The KMS key you specify in the policy must use the `arn:aws:kms:region:acct-id:key/key-id` format.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingKMSEncryption.html

An alias would not be consistent with the concept of requiring "a specific KMS key" as mentioned above, since an alias does not refer to a specific key, except transiently while the alias happens to point to the key.

Also:

> You can use an alias as the value of the KeyId parameter only in the following operations:
>
> - `DescribeKey`
> - `Encrypt`
> - `GenerateDataKey`
> - `GenerateDataKeyWithoutPlaintext`
> - `ReEncrypt`
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/programming-aliases.html